# Show process and service owner in windows environment

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I was wondering if it's possible to show a Process/Service name and it's Owner(!) on a targeted machine.

Is it possible? Should I use the WMI module for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the WMI, try the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. Use the `Name` property to ge the Name of the process and the [`GetOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for get the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but I would prefer [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/).

Comment: is psutil is a module? How can I use it?

Comment: and does this "psutil" can target network machines? seems to me psutil is only locally..!

Comment: Sorry, just got back to my machine. It's a third party module. The docs and other things for it are located in that link I attached. I've never used it for anything other than my own local machine though, so I cannot answer whether it works or not on networked machine.

Comment: I downloaded it and tried to figure out whats going on, seems that i cant use net locations.